# jquery alert box simple calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I want to make simple calculation using js and jQuery.  Regarding the values in fields, alertbox should display calculation. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head >
    <body>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn1").click(function(){
                    alert("Solution: " + $("#demo").val());
                });
            });
            
            function myFunction(a, b) {
                var a;
                var b;
                return a * b;
            }

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(a, b);
        </script>

        <input id="a" type="text" value="10" />
        <input id="b" type="text" value="5" />
        <button id="btn1">Result</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#demo").val()` This code will return empty result because the `<p>` is not a form element. Change to `$("#demo").html()` or `$("#demo").text()`

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work, I got alert box and text "Solution: " without calculation

Comment: why are you create `var a; var b;` in `myFunction`? `a` and `b` are already declared in the function signature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        //Grab Values
        $('#demo').val(myFunction($('#a').val(), $('#b').val()));

        $("#btn1").click(function(){
           alert("Solution: " + $("#demo").val());
        });
    });
    function myFunction(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    }
</script> 

<input id = "a" type = "text" value = "10" /> 
<input id = "b" type = "text" value = "5" /> <button id = "btn1"> Result </button>
```

Comment: You got it! No problem!

Comment: can you just tell me.. in the part where you grab values,  you put variables a and b in #demo? That is why is it called in alert on this way or?

Comment: The first line there gets the values from the inputs, then calls the function to process them, and finally sets the value of demo to the returned value of the function. Then when you click the button, it grabs the value of demo, and alerts it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are particular about using the paragraph element you cannot access the paragraph element by Id but access by tag name instead. Your code can be modified to such for achieving the result:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btn1").click(function(){
  alert("Solution: " + document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML);
});

  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = myFunction($('#a').val(), $('#b').val());
});
function myFunction(a, b) {
var a;
var b;
return a * b;
}

</script >
</head>
<body>

  <p id='demo'></p>
  <input type='text' value='10' id='a'>
  <input type='text' value='5' id='b'>
  <button id='btn1'>Result</button>
</body>
```

Hope this helps